# JavaFX - How to check if a Datepicker has valid input

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making a to-do list in JavaFX. I want people to choose a deadline, so I'm using a Datepicker. However, I can't find out how to check if a person has input a valid Date. Can anybody help me with this?

If it is invalid, I want the system to alert the user with invalid input. Say I don't enter a label and/or datepicker, Java will alert the user with this invalid input by making use of a StringBuilder

With invalid input, I mean "Not a Date" and/or no input at all

Edit: I found it! The datepicker has a .getValue() method I can check if it has a null value.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 1):

You can get the DatePicker’s text directly from its [editor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html#getEditor%28%29), and pass it to the DatePicker’s [converter](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html#getConverter%28%29):

```
try {
    datePicker.getConverter().fromString(
        datePicker.getEditor().getText());
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    // Alert user here
}
```